# Matplotlib bar chart that displays the x values for male and females

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, bar-chart

I want to try analyse the distribution of marital status by gender and I feel a bar chart is the best to way to go. I can figure out how to get the number of people per marital status but can't figure out how to split the result for male and female for each status. I've watched a lot of tutorials for bar charts in matplotlib using pandas but I can't seem to get it.

Dataframe:

[image]

Series structure with the values as number of people:

[image: Series]

This is what I did to plot for just the number of people per status:

```
series = dfFile["marital_status"].value_counts()

series.plot('bar')
plt.show()
```

What I'm getting:

[image: Graph displayed]

What I want to get is something like this but with the x values as marital status:

[image]

Quite new to Python and Matplotlib so I appoligise if the answer is obvious or if the question isn't worded very well.

Comment: this is about manipulating / analyzing data with pandas and without knowing what your dataframe contains we can't help, the plotting bit is kinda obvious after that.

Comment: Ah I see, I've edited the question to include the dataframe. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should help:

```
gender_column = <ENTER GENDER COLUMN NAME HERE>
dfFile.groupby(["marital_status", gender_column]).size().unstack(level=1).plot(kind='bar')
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but that prints two bars (male and female) but I'd like to have a bar for male and female for every type of marital status. So in total there would be 14 bars (7 marital status X 2 genders)

Comment: Edited, the solution above will give you (7 marital status X 2 genders)

Comment: Not sure if I did something wrong but it's giving me the same result as I got from the code posted in the question only in a random order. Is this because the male bars are hiding behind the female bars or visa versa so I need to offset the x values for one of the genders? I've edited the question to include a graph very similar to the results I would like to achieve.

Comment: Edited once more. Now you should get the male and female bars you wanted

Comment: Thanks so much, I know it sounds ridiculous but I've spent the last two days trying to figure this out. I can see it's very simple but for whatever reason I just can't get my head around it. You're a life saver

Comment: The `unstack` method will be your freind in the future. Learn more about it here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html